# How to insert field in already existing nested documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a985f67962d91c0f3a1f6"), 
    "Email" : "abc@gmail.com", 
    "PhoneNumber" : "9999999999", 
    "TwoFactorEnabled" : false, 
    "LockoutEndDateUtc" : null, 
    "LockoutEnabled" : true, 
    "AccessFailedCount" : NumberInt(0), 

    "DisplayName" : "Nilesh Guria", 
    "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2016-12-21T14:57:35.379+0000"), 
    "UpdatedOn" : ISODate("2018-09-17T21:32:16.027+0000"),  
    "Wallet" : {
        "Balance" : 1000,
        "UnbilledUsage": 100
    }
}
```

I want to add a field called "CustomerCredit" with a default value of 0 inside the "Wallet" field in all such documents. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python shell.

```
db.collection.update_many({"$set": {"Wallet.CustomerCredit": 0}})
```

You can use update_many since update is now deprecated.
From mongoshell

```
db.collection.updateMany({},{$set: {"Wallet.CustomerCredit": 0}})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection("collectionName")
  .updateMany({ "Wallet.CustomerCredit": { $exists: false }},
          { $set:{ "Wallet.CustomerCredit": 0 }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields{
             "Wallet.CustomerCredit": 0
        }
    }
])
```

See the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)